# Simple .Show function not displaying DIV on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a check box on my page "cbxShowNotifications." If it is checked when the page loads, I want to SHOW "treeview."

.aspx page:

```
<html> 
      <body>
        <form>
           <asp:CheckBox ID="cbxShowNotifications" runat="server"/>Show Notifications
           <div id="treeview"></div>
        </form>
        <script src="../Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="../Scripts/kendo.web.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="../Scripts/NotificationsTreeView.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                showOrHide();
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                CreateNotificationTree(<%= UserId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) %>);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript file:

```
function CreateNotificationTree(userId)
{
    var data = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "../api/notifications/byuserid/" + userId,
                contentType: "application/json"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                children: "notifications"
            }
        }
    });

    $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
        dataSource: data,
        loadOnDemand: true,
        dataUrlField: "LinksTo",
        checkboxes: {
            checkChildren: true
        },
        dataTextField: ["notificationType", "NotificationDesc"],
        select: treeviewSelect
    });

    function treeviewSelect(e)
    {
        var node = this.dataItem(e.node);
        window.open(node.NotificationLink, "_self");
    }
}

$('#cbxShowNotifications').on('change', function()
{
    debugger;
    var tview = $('#treeview');

    if ($(this).prop('checked'))
    {
        tview.show();
    }
    else
    {
        tview.hide();
    }
});

function showOrHide()
{
    debugger;
    var tview = $('#cbxShowNotifications');

    if ($(this).prop('checked'))
    {
        tview.show();
    }
    else
    {
        tview.hide();
    }
}
```

The problem is, when the page loads AND the check box is checked, the treeview is NOT visible. What am I doing wrong?

By the way, after the page is loaded, if I uncheck the checkbox, the tree disappears and if I check it, it appears.

So this is only happening at page load which leads me to believe it's an issue of WHEN things are being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function `showOrHide`

change:

```
if ($(this).prop('checked'))
```

to

```
if ($('#cbxShowNotifications').prop('checked'))
```

The `this` value is not a checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

The checkbox `cbxShowNotifications` is a .net server control. So, the ID won't remain the same. Observe the change in the DOM that the ID gets prepended with Page & control information i.e., something similar to "master_ctrl_cbxShowNotifications"

I suggest you to add a class to it & use the class as a selector.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbxShowNotifications" CssClass="chkBoxNotif" runat="server"/>

$('.chkBoxNotif').on('change', function(event) {
    //Do something
});
```